# MYSQL/PHP: Possible to Join on One to Many Field?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have three tables, authors, books and borrowed.  There are multiple books for each author.  And a book may or not appear in the borrowed table.  Here is the schema:

Authors

```
id|authornamename
```

Books

```
id|bookname|authorid
```

Borrowed

```
id|bookid|borrowerid|onloan //onloan is a boolean
```

Whenever a book is borrowed, it appears in the Borrowed table.  However, only some books appear in the borrowed table.  If ever borrowed, they can have value for onloan of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

The following query returns a list of authors with a comma-delimitied list of bookids and booknames by each:

```
SELECT 
a.*,a.id as `authorid`, bookids,booknames 
from authors `a` 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT group_concat(id ORDER BY id ASC) as `bookids`,
group_concat(bookname ORDER BY id ASC) as `booknames` 
   FROM   books
   GROUP  BY authorid
   ) b ON b.authorid = a.id 
GROUP BY a.id";
```

How could I also get, a list for each book of whether the book is borrowed (onloan field) given that there is not an entry for each book in the borrowed table?  I would like the list of onloan to have the same number of entries as books, so I can tell if a book is onloan at a given time.  If it has never been borrowed, I would like to have a value of 0--ie the same value as if it had been borrowed but Onloan was `FALSE`.

So if the bookids list is something like:

```
"32,77,84"
```

The onloan list should be something like

```
"0,1,1"
```

where 1 means it is onloan (out) and 0 means it is not onloan (in library).

I need the onloan list to have the same number of elements as the bookids list so there is a 1 to 1 correspondence between the to and I can laster use the index to reassemble a books array.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  aid, 
  group_concat(bookid ORDER BY bookid ASC) AS bookids, 
  group_concat(bookname ORDER BY bookid ASC) AS booknames, 
  group_concat(onloan ORDER BY bookid ASC) AS onloan
FROM (
  SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bookid, b.bookname AS bookname, IF(bo.onloan IS NOT NULL, bo.onloan, 0) AS onloan
  FROM authors a
  LEFT JOIN books b ON b.authorid = a.id
  LEFT JOIN borrowed bo ON bo.bookid = b.id
) t
GROUP BY aid
```

Notice the `IF`. That guarantees you have always a result for `onloan`.

Comment: This looks right but for some reason I am getting unknown column bo.onloan in field list error

Comment: Would you mind proofreading your answer again.  I keep getting a sql error.  Should the alias names bookids, booknames have an 's' at end?  Is there any significance to the t after the ) at the end of the FROM clause?  Should that perhaps be 's'?  I have tried it numerous ways but keep getting errors, most recently near (onloan...in line 5

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, I think, with a couple changes,  after booknames there should be a comma and after the select clause should be b, not t.  Thx!

Comment: The `t` is just a requirement of mysql, that every "table" (even subselects) need a name, but does not matter. You can use whatever you like as name after `AS`, I just used the one you provided.

Comment: You are right. That comma slipped by me. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ok.  Thx, just confirmed that the letter after the from clause does not matter...

Comment: I discovered that this is not working correctly.  For a query where there should be nine books, I am getting sixteen times that many results in in the group_concats. I have a feeling that the query is returning a product of the extra table queried.

Comment: This was the problem that originally led me to go with the subquery structure in my question.  It seems to be occurring again in the absence of a subquery structure